# Is it possible to be able to increment a particular column value (int) by one via php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql

I have a button on a page that I would like use to increase the value of a column in a particular row of my database by 1. I have an idea of how I will parse the info except not entirely 100% on the sql e within my 'bridging' php file.

I'm thinking it will be an update statement but I'm not sure whether I can use `i++` or something similar to increase the values by one.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE markers SET verification = "???" WHERE name="somename")
```

The system I'm trying to build is a bit of an upvote/downvote system which the current 'numbervalue' is stored in the db, for use elsewhere within the page. 
How can I do this? Cheers

Comment: `SET verification = verification + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could increment them by one using your query with this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE markers SET verification = verification + 1 WHERE name='somename'");
```

Sidenote: And if possible, use a newer API which is mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: is there any reason why it would be automatically clearing the rest of that row besides the values after the WHERE clause, even though I am only 'reseting' the verification column?

Comment: All good, was something else somewhere else causing it.